# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error while browsing youtube.com in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, browser, certificate

While browsing https://www.youtube.com from any browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, IE), I am getting the same error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID . It is about certificate issue. When I check the site certificate, it shows other than google.com in Issued to. 
But gmail and other google serviecs are working well.

How can we change the certificate of youtube.com in our browser to *.google.com ? The details about this is attached in screenshot below. [image]

Comment: First search result for that error code: https://www.xtremerain.com/fix-err-cert-common-name-invalid Have you tried some of these?

Comment: Yes. I already tried with all the options as mentioned in that site: adjusting date,time of PC, using Google DNS, clearing browser cache etc. But still no luck.

Comment: Browsers no longer use "Issued to", they use "Detail → Subject Alternative Name". What domains are listed there?

Comment: The domains listed are DNS Name=edgestatic.com
DNS Name=*.edgestatic.com
DNS Name=*.gvt5.com
DNS Name=i.ytimg.com
DNS Name=play-lh.googleusercontent.com

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka - I presume your security software is configured to scan your secure HTTP traffic?  The certificate your browser is trying to use isn’t signed owned by Google.  Are you connected to an enterprise network?

Comment: Yes, I am connected to enterprise network. For same network, I can access youtube  from other PCs.